# Solr Atomic field update should happen only if new value is bigger

Tags: javascript, solr, updates, atomic, processor

I have a custom string field in Solr which holds a timestamp. I update some documents which have this field by atomic updates. For example:

```
{id:doc1, last_interact:{set:8888} }
```

Now let's say the doc1 exists and it's last_interact field already has a value.
I want the atomic update to happen only if the new value is bigger than the existing value. So for example if the current value of last_interact is 555 the above update is allowed to change the last_interact value since it's increasing it. But if the current value is 99999, the update shouldn't change the value.

How to achieve this?

I have already tried with implementing a StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory processor and in the java script file in the function processAdd(cmd){} apply the rule, but no success yet; because in this function I have access to the fields of submitted document but not to the fields of existing document.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in solution in Solr.

You could:

1. before sending the update, check the value with a query from the client side.
2. modify your UpdateRequestProcessor, and just look up the value from there with a query, nothing prevents you from issuing a query inside the URP. This would be more work but your client code would not need to worry about it.

Comment: In the 2nd way, can you elaborate on how to query Solr from inside the UpdateRequestProcessor JS file please.

Comment: I write my URPs in Java, not JS, but you can do whatever you need to, you can send a query to Solr in js right? you can post a URL etc